# Continuous Loop Code in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

This is my first course in java. when I am writing this code it is just stop when it prints the gcd. I want the code to start again from the beginning and continue. Since I didn't take any complicated codes in the course, as I am not allowed to. The program is about a loop that subtract the smaller integer from the larger one and Continue looping until one of the integers becomes zero, so that it prints out the non-zero integer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first integer: ");

        while (in.hasNextInt() || in.hasNext()) {

            while (in.hasNextInt() || in.hasNext()) {
                int x = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("x = " + x);
                System.out.println("Enter the second integer: ");
                int y = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("y = " + y);

                while (x != 0) {
                    while (x >= y) {
                        int a = Math.max(x, y);
                        int b = Math.min(x, y);
                        a = a - b;
                        x = a;
                        y = b;
                    }
                    while (x < y) {
                        int a = Math.min(x, y);
                        int b = Math.max(x, y);
                        b = b - a;
                        x = a;
                        y = b;
                    }

                    System.out.println("The gcd =" + y);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (in.hasNextInt() || in.hasNext()) { ... }` why do you have two `while` loops with the same condition?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Idk, maybe i though that it l would repeat the whole code

Comment: You may want to use if and else statement inside the while(x! =0) loop

Comment: `while(true)` and `for(;;)` creates infinite loops (unless you break or return).

Comment: when I do this it prints 4 numbers without looping from the beginning, but after I changed the place of the sop, it prints the right number but without looping @Ajay

Comment: the first print needs to go inside the endless loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are using while loop incorrectly. Make sure to make effective use of if statements as well as classes (If you know how to use them).

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the first integer: ");

    int x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    System.out.println("Enter the second integer: ");
    int y = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("y = " + y);

    while (x != 0) {
        if (x >= y) {
           int a = Math.max(x, y);
           int b = Math.min(x, y);
           a = a - b;
           x = a;
           y = b;
        }else if (x<y){

           int a = Math.min(x, y);
           int b = Math.max(x, y);
           b = b - a;
           x = a;
           y = b;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The gcd =" + y);


  }

}
```

Try this (should work fine).

Comment: Even though it was not looping, but it helped me and I got the answer. Thanks :D  @marshmellooooooos

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle this problem:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
System.out.println("Enter the first integer: ");
while(in.hasNextInt() ==false) {
}
int x = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("x = " + x);
System.out.println("Enter the second integer: ");
while(in.hasNextInt() ==false) {
}
int y = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("y = " + y);

while (x != 0 && y != 0) {
    if (x >= y) {
       x = x - y ;
    }else if (x<y){
       y = y - x ;
    }
}
if(x != 0) {
System.out.println("The gcd is " + x) ;
} else {
System.out.println("The gcd is " + y) ;
}
}
```

The code will wait until a user inputs the integers before starting execution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I want, Thanks 4 the help everyone :D

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first integer: ");
    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    int x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    System.out.println("Enter the second integer: ");
    int y = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("y = " + y);

while (x != 0) {
    if (x >= y) {
       int a = Math.max(x, y);
       int b = Math.min(x, y);
       a = a - b;
       x = a;
       y = b;
    }else if (x<y){

       int a = Math.min(x, y);
       int b = Math.max(x, y);
       b = b - a;
       x = a;
       y = b;
    }
}

System.out.println("The gcd =" + y);
System.out.println("Enter the first integer: ");



 }

    }

}
```